# Recursive descent vs recursive ascent parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, lalr

If I'm writing my own custom parser, how can I know if I'm writing a recursive ascent parser? I'm definitely interested in the O(n) complexity of LALR parsing (plus I already have a LALR grammar) and don't want to find out later that I've written an LL parser instead.

Edit: I've only ever seen automatic table-driven parsers and a couple generated simple example recursive parsers- none of which look remotely like anything I'd construct by hand. So it's kind of hard to associate the "obvious" code to deal with a rule with an actual algorithm.

If you take the code for a relatively simple rule, for example

```
name_or_qualified_name = identifier *('.' identifier);
```

which I've translated into

```
std::vector<std::wstring> RecursiveParseNameOrQualifiedName(Iterator& begin, Iterator end) {
    std::vector<std::wstring> retval;
    retval.push_back(begin->Codepoints);
    CheckedIncrement(begin, end); // The only place that can legitimately expect end of input is namespace contents.
    while(begin->type == Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Dot) {
        CheckedIncrement(begin, end);
        if (begin->type != Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier)
            Wide::ParserExceptionBuilder(*begin) << L"Expected 'identifier' after '.'";
        retval.push_back(begin->Codepoints);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

There's nothing very left or right about it. It's obviously useful and important information to know, and I'm not seeing it. The only obvious fact here is that it's recursive.

Edit: Sorry, bad example. How about something like this:

```
void RecursiveParseUsing(Iterator& begin, Iterator end, Wide::Parser::NamespaceAST* current_namespace) {
    auto new_using = std::unique_ptr<Wide::Parser::UsingAST>( new Wide::Parser::UsingAST() );
    // expect "begin" to point to a using
    CheckedIncrement(begin, end);
    // Must be an identifier, at least
    if (begin->type != Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier)
        Wide::ParserExceptionBuilder(*begin) << L"Expected 'identifier' after 'using'";
    CheckedIncrement(begin, end);
    switch(begin->type) {
    case Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Dot: {
        begin--; // back to identifier
        new_using->original_name = RecursiveParseNameOrQualifiedName(begin, end);
        current_namespace->unnamed_contents.push_back(std::move(new_using));
        break; }
    case Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Equals: {
        begin--; // back to Identifier
        new_using->new_name = begin->Codepoints;
        begin++; // Back to equals
        begin++; // The token ahead of equals- should be "identifier"
        new_using->original_name = RecursiveParseNameOrQualifiedName(begin, end); // The only valid next production
        // this should be left at the one past the name
        current_namespace->contents[new_using->new_name] = std::move(new_using);
        break; }
    case Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Semicolon: {
        begin--; // Identifier
        new_using->original_name.push_back(begin->Codepoints);
        begin++; // Semicolon
        current_namespace->unnamed_contents.push_back(std::move(new_using));
        break; }
    default:
        Wide::ParserExceptionBuilder(*begin) << L"Expected '.', '=' or ';' after 'identifier' when parsing 'using'.";
    }
    if (begin->type != Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Semicolon)
        Wide::ParserExceptionBuilder(*begin) << L"Expected ';' after 'identifier'";
    CheckedIncrement(begin, end); // One-past-the-end
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You are writing a parser and you don't know if it's a recursive descent one or not? It means you're just writing statements while in trance or what?

Comment: @6502: The only examples I've ever seen are automatically generated. They don't exactly correspond to code I'd write myself.

Comment: It's hard to tell by looking at an example where you're not calling other parse functions (you're only calling the lexer)... but I'd bet your is a recursive descent parser. What type of language is it? Not a C-like language I suppose (or otherwise how are things like `a.b[4].c().d` parsed? dot should be an operator...).

Answer (score 3):

Both LL and LALR are O(n), so it doesn't matter.

However, not all recursive descent parsers are LL.  Those that aren't use some form of backtracking ­– trying one production and when it doesn't work trying another until all possible productions have been exhausted or a successful parse is found.  It's not very difficult to notice that you are doing this :-)

As to how you know whether you are constructing a LL or LALR parser – you know it by being aware of which construction method you are following.

Edited to add: One distinguishing feature between recursive descent and recursive ascent is the role of the procedures.  In recursive descent, you have a procedure for each nonterminal.  In recursive ascent, you have a procedure for each LR state.  In order to have the latter, you pretty much have to construct the LR automaton beforehand (unless you've done this so often that you can do it on the fly – but in that case you wouldn't be asking this question).  Your first code example looks like recursive descent; but you did not tell us how the second code sample relates to your grammar so it's difficult to tell there.

Comment: I'm following the method of "This is the obvious thing to do.".

Comment: Well, then you are in a bind.  But one thing distinguishing between recursive descent and recursive ascent is the job of the procedure: are your procedures nonterminals or are they LALR states?  If you haven't constructed the LALR automaton, then you probably aren't writing a LALR parser.